# How to get a value from any .js file with module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I am new to JS and programming in general, so please explain with that in mind. I know that this question is not formulated very well, but I couldn't think of how to formulate it better so feel free to edit it. I am making a discord bot with discord.js. I have made a command called 'test'.
My code is as follows (in a file named test.js):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'test',
    description: 'Test command. Sends back "Test successful."',
    prefixType: 'devPrefix',
    execute(msg, args) {
        if (!args.length){
            msg.channel.send('Test successful.');
        } else {
            msg.channel.send('Test successful. You entered ' + args.length + ' argument(s).')
        }   
    },
};
```

How do i get the value `prefixType` and use it in my main index.js file? However the solution needs to work for any file in a folder (called 'commands'), not just with test.js.

If this helps, I am including the code in my main index.js file that deals with handling and executing commands:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');   //For commands (fs = file system)
const botClient = new Discord.Client;
const CONFIG = require('./config.json');

//Get the commands
botClient.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    botClient.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

botClient.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online and ready.');
});

botClient.on('message', msg => {
    if ((!msg.content.startsWith(CONFIG.prefix) && !msg.content.startsWith(CONFIG.devPrefix)) 
        || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(CONFIG.prefix.length).split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    //If the command doesn't exist
    if (!botClient.commands.has(commandName)){
        msg.reply("That command does not exist. Do a.commands for a list of all commands");
        return;
    }

    const command = botClient.commands.get(commandName);

    try {
        command.execute(msg, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('Error when trying to get and execute a command.');
        msg.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command.');     
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `require('test.js').prefixType`?

Comment: Or `const { prefixType } = require('test')`

Comment: @terrymorse Thanks, but this needs to work with any file, not just test.js (like i said in the question).

Comment: @terrymorse are you sure? Can you not use something similar to `require(\`./commands/${file}\`);`

Comment: @cs09 You're right, you can specify the require path with a string variable. So `const { prefixType } = require(filePath)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you export that in command file, which you later require and put into `botClient.commands` Collection, you can access `prefixType` anywhere else you have access to your `client`.  `botClient.commands.get('test').prefixType` will give you that property.

Additionally, you can access `client` property from most of Discord.js structures, like `Message` or `User` by doing `message.client` or `user.client`. And since your Collection of commands is attached to your client object, you can access it like in example above.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I stated in the question this needs to work dynamically with any .js file, not just test.js.

Comment: So it's `botClient.commands.get(commandName).prefixType` or where do you want to use it?

Comment: @Sven31415 Yes, that works, thank you. Can i also use this to get any const or let inside the `execute{}` block?

Comment: Not really, as `let` and `const` are block scoped, so they are limited to that `execute` only. You would have to either return them from there, or have other exported object to export to outside of the file, and use it from it inside the file.